# Cannot Run Mongo as Service

Tags: linux, mongodb, service, centos

### My Environment

- CentOS (I'm not sure the exact version since it's on iPage's VPS server.)

### My Goal

Start mongod as a service:

```
sudo service mongod start
```

(Once I get this working, I want to get mongod to start when the server reboots via chkconfig:

```
sudo /sbin/chkconfig --level 345 mongod on
```

)

### What Happens

It comes back with [FAILED] and I get this message in my logs:

```
2014-08-27T03:17:40.126+0000 ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2014-08-27T03:17:40.132+0000 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=3950 port=27017    dbpath=/var/lib/mongo 64-bit host=162-144-108-42.ipage.com
2014-08-27T03:17:40.132+0000 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.4
2014-08-27T03:17:40.132+0000 [initandlisten] git version: 3a830be0eb92d772aa855ebb711ac91d658ee910
2014-08-27T03:17:40.132+0000 [initandlisten] build info: Linux build7.nj1.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2014-08-27T03:17:40.132+0000 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2014-08-27T03:17:40.132+0000 [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1" }, processManagement: { fork: true, pidFilePath: "/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongo" }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2014-08-27T03:17:40.133+0000 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10309 Unable to create/open lock file: /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2014-08-27T03:17:40.133+0000 [initandlisten] dbexit: 
2014-08-27T03:17:40.133+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2014-08-27T03:17:40.133+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2014-08-27T03:17:40.133+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2014-08-27T03:17:40.133+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2014-08-27T03:17:40.133+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2014-08-27T03:17:40.133+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2014-08-27T03:17:40.133+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2014-08-27T03:17:40.133+0000 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2014-08-27T03:17:40.133+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2014-08-27T03:17:40.133+0000 [initandlisten] couldn't remove fs lock errno:9 Bad file descriptor
2014-08-27T03:17:40.133+0000 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

### What I've Tried:

- Grepping the current processes doesn't find any mongod process:

  ps aux | grep mongod
- Removing the mongod.lock file doesn't help:

  sudo rm mongod.lock
- Changing the owner of the database doesn't help:

  sudo chown -R my_username /var/lib/mongo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a permissions issue:

```
2014-08-27T03:17:40.133+0000 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10309 Unable to create/open lock file: /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
```

Look if the user which mongo is running has the permission to write on that folder, assuming you're already removed the .lock file.

You are using chown with your username, but it seems that user must be mongo, not your username. Check the ownwer when the service tries to startup.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying to do sudo chown -R mongodb /var/lib/mongo?

Comment: @NoBrainer At least in Fedora the mongodb is the user. You can check your init scripts in /etc/init.d/

Comment: Here's the exact command that worked for me: sudo chown -R mongod /var/lib/mongo

Answer (score 1):

I was able to verify running `sudo chown -R mongodb /var/lib/mongo` works on my CentOS system.  My /etc/init.d/mongod script runs the mongod process as user mongod.  When I did a sudo chown -R root /var/lib/mongo I received the same Permission denied error, but when I set the directory permissions as mongod (`sudo chown -R mongodb /var/lib/mongo`) running `sudo service mongod start` works